# Getting ripped off by a vending machine

Tags: theft

I bought something from a vending machine and it only gave me 6 dollars in change when it should've given me 9. This is stealing and I was very unhappy but didn't want to waste my time asking the owner to get my $3 back because it would be a hassle and 20 minutes of my time is very valuable, worth much more than $3. Can I ask the manager for 20 dollars refund because of the cost of my time?

Comment: You are entitled to be made whole, not necessarily compensated for your time/frustration. It also doesn't really fall under "theft", it is simply malfunctioning equipment.

Comment: It's very doubtful the manager owns the vending machines and would have nothing to do with their management or refunds.

Comment: Can I ask for a $20 refund for the time I spent reading this?

Comment: But you chose to read this and I didnt choose to get ripped off by the vending machine. I guess I'll just have to lose the $3 and deal with it instead of wasting my time, as much as I don't like getting ripped off.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask the manager, but you probably won't get.

Your legal entitlement is to $3 of compensatory damages period and maybe court costs if any if a lawsuit is brought.

Without an intent to steal (which is unlikely) it isn't theft, it is just a breach of a contract for the sale of goods, or unjust enrichment.